# Craft Commerce Digital Products delete multiples

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-digitalproducts

Craft Commerce Digital Products:

Why aren't there checkboxes next to the product names so I can delete multiple items at once?

It exists in regular Craft Commerce Products.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a technical reason for this, but feel free to make a feature request requesting it: https://github.com/craftcms/digital-products/issues